# colspan in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to re-organize a table from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

using only CSS. Reason being is that on a desktop there is much more space than on a smartphone screen. Therefore I want the table cells to be displayed underneath each other for a smaller resolution.

I tried to take the colspan and rowspan attributes out of my HTML file and put them into the CSS stylesheet but that doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible at all to do this in CSS alone?

Comment: post your html also css if needed

Comment: Maybe you could use flexbox with order and 100% width sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use media query for small screen and `display:block` for every row.

Comment: Welcome ...My Pleasure :)